# Can I use iText7 to sign a PDF using a smartcard?

Tags: c#, itext7

I used Spire.PDF to sign a PDF document using my smartcard with something like this:

```cs
   using (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument())
   {
    document.LoadFromFile(@"F:\file.pdf");
    using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
    {
     store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
     X509Certificate2Collection storecollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(store.Certificates, null,null,  X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
     using (PdfCertificate cert = new PdfCertificate(storecollection[0].RawData))
     {
      PdfSignature signature = new PdfSignature(document, document.Pages[0], cert, "signature0")
      {
       Date = DateTime.Now,
       DocumentPermissions = PdfCertificationFlags.AllowFormFill | PdfCertificationFlags.ForbidChanges,
       Certificated = true
      };
      document.SaveToFile(@"F:\signedfile.pdf");
      document.Close();
     }
    }
   }
```

Is it possible to do the same with iText7? I cannot find a modern and simple example on how to to it.
Most examples I read are about iTextSharp and have really complicated material.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: we are currently updating the iText7 digital signature examples, but haven't gotten to the smart cards for .NET yet. We do have the Java example ready, which you can find [here](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7JS/repos/signatures/browse/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures/chapter04/C4_03_SignWithPKCS11SC.java?at=refs%2Fheads%2FDEVSIX-3395) (hope it helps!).

Comment: (the Belgian eID card is used in the example)